# Adjusting rig after generation (Rigify)

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify

*I'm not an English speaker, sorry for mistakes*.

I spend several weeks to create my first character, but few days ago i figured out that rig is set up incorrectly. Severals manipulator have wrong rotation. Look at the first screenshot.

[image]

It is the cause of wrong and unnatural arm movements and deformations. I can't fix rotation manually, because every time i try to do it, i get wrong deformations of my mesh and other troubles.
**Do i have an ability to adjust rig after generation? What is the way to do it?**

I tried to delete Armature modifiers, tried to clear parents and set it again - it isn't working.

After this, i decided to start from the very beginning and set up rig again. I did it correctly (as i think). Look at the second screen.

[image]

I set up bones exactly like they need to be set up. I mean that they follow my mesh and axis are correct. But after generation i get the same situation (1st screen). Why?
**What am i doing wrong?**

Yeah, maybe my rig isn't perfect, i can see that one bone have more length, but i think it isn't a case of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately my answer got ignored, but **I think i did it**.

I've found out that i can adjust the skeleton. But there is the need to do a few steps:
1. Apply Armature modifier.
2. Select rig, go to edit mode and adjust all you need to adjust.
3. In pose mode apply current pose as rest pose.
4. Set Armature back.

It works for me. Yeah, i still didn't get the best result, but i'm trying. Maybe i'll add more information.

Answer (score 0):

In your second image, notice that the z-axis of the upper arm is pointing up while the lower arm is pointing forward. The [bone roll](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/bones/editing/transform.html#bone-roll) is used to rotate the bone on its y-axis to determine which way the x and z axes point.

[image: bone roll highlighted]

This bone roll also determines the alignment of the [custom shapes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/bones/properties/display.html) that are shown in place of the bones, which you refer to as manipulators. If each bone has a roll that aligns the x-axis differently, then each custom shape will be shown in a different orientation.

The custom shapes can be adjusted by editing the mesh object, in edit mode, so that it aligns with your rig. This may mean using more than one custom shape for a rig if you need to adjust matching bones differently.